# FileNotFoundError: Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor: Failed to find any matching files for ../Saved_Model/1\variables\variables

Tags: python, gpu, tensorflow2.0, fastapi

I am trying to build a image classifier API. Built the model using Google Colab becasue i dont have a GPU. Am using CPU and donwloaded the model into the API application.

But get this error when i try to access my model directory Saved_Model.
I know its to do with GPU and CUDA settings but i cant tell what exaclty is wrong or how sort it since am using CPU.

Complete Error:

```
    Elijah-A-W@DESKTOP-34M2E8U MINGW64 /d/myn/ML Prediction Project/New folder/Detection Potato Lite/Api
$ python main.py
2022-07-29 09:12:32.654485: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 
'cudart64_110.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_110.dll not found
2022-07-29 09:12:32.670439: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not 
have a GPU set up on your machine.
2022-07-29 09:13:18.928444: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 
'nvcuda.dll'; dlerror: nvcuda.dll not found
2022-07-29 09:13:18.928809: W tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:269] failed call to cuInit: UNKNOWN ERROR (303)
2022-07-29 09:13:18.934497: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:169] retrieving CUDA diagnostic information for host: DESKTOP-34M2E8U
2022-07-29 09:13:18.935291: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:176] hostname: DESKTOP-34M2E8U
2022-07-29 09:13:19.068867: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:193] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX AVX2
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\myn\ML Prediction Project\New folder\Detection Potato Lite\Api\main.py", line 10, in <module>
    MODEL = tf.keras.models.load_model("../Saved_Model/1")
  File "C:\Users\Elijah-A-W\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 67, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "C:\Users\Elijah-A-W\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\saved_model\load.py", line 915, in load_partial
    raise FileNotFoundError(
FileNotFoundError: Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor: Failed to find any matching files for ../Saved_Model/1\variables\variables
 You may be trying to load on a different device from the computational device. Consider setting the `experimental_io_device` option in `tf.saved_model.LoadOptions` to the io_device such as '/job:localhost'.
```

The Complete code:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, File, UploadFile
import uvicorn 
import numpy as np
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image
import tensorflow as tf

app = FastAPI()

MODEL = tf.keras.models.load_model("../Saved_Model/1")
CLASS_NAMES = ["Early Blight", "Late Blight", "Healthy"]


@app.get("/ping")
async def ping():
    return "hello, I am alive"

async def read_file_as_image(data) -> np.ndarray:
    image = np.array(Image.open(BytesIO(data)))     # reading an image as byte & converting into array 
    img_batch = np.expand_dims(image, 0)            # adding extra dimesnion to the loaded img batch 
    prediction = MODEL.predict(img_batch)           # calling the model predict the image batch
    pass

@app.post("/predict")
async def predict(file: UploadFile = File(...)):
    image = read_file_as_image(await file.read())
    return image 

if __name__ == "__main__":
 
    uvicorn.run(app, host='localhost', port=5000)
```

This is the image of the Project directories
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

This is the
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4Bg0.png

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and tried this.

Then it worked.

```
from keras.models import load_model
model.save('model.h5')
model_final = load_model('model.h5')
```